# how to save and close excel file in R using Shell()

Tags: r, excel, shell

I have an excel file that queries Olap cube using DAX.

For some unfortunate reasons with DBAs, this is currently only viable way for me to load cube data into R.

So I am trying to automatize opening, refreshing, and closing excel file using R script, instead of doing that manually.

After some web search, I am able to open the excel file using Shell(). And the excel file is set to refresh itself when it is opened.

What come's next is where I need help; I want to save this file (like Ctrl + S) and close it. So I can load it to my R.

```
#open excel file
 shell.exec("zero_billed_cases.xlsx") 

#save excel file
 "How do I do this?"

#close excel file (this is what I found online, but this only opens the file)
 shell('\"zero_billed_cases.xlsx\"')
```

Thanks for your time and effort!

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the following approach :

```
library(RDCOMClient)

path_Excel_File <- "D:\\zero_billed_cases.xlsx"

xlApp <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
xlApp[["Visible"]] <- TRUE
xlWbk <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open(path_Excel_File)

xlWbk$SaveAs(path_Excel_File)
xlWbk$Close()
```

With the RDCOMClient, we can take control of an already opened Excel file.